# Does Googlebot see dynamically loaded content?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, ajax, dynamic

Our modelling agency website uses the Photolux Wordpress theme. Our front page uses the same masonry template. The only difference is that we've modified the masonry elements to link to a post instead of hashes.

When viewing as Google in webmaster tools, it does not see those links, which is a big problem, since we want them to be searchable. In our sitemap, we put those posts and also used Google's data highlighter.

My question would be that is it a big setback that the bot doesn't see those links? If yes, how should I fix that?

Comment: There is not enough detail here for a solid answer. However, Googlebot does run JS and should understand most of the things you want to do, however, having said that, not all links made with JS can be easily understood by spiders. You do have to be careful of that. It may help others to answer your question if you gave us some examples of how the code/links have changed. How are you using GWT? Are you using Fetch as Google and Render? How? The more you can tell us the better. Plus, no question ever went unanswered for being too verbose, however, not enough detail and we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it is a problem if Google, or any search engine, can not crawl through those links. I would fix it.

> My question would be that is it a big setback that the bot doesn't see
>   those links? If yes, how should I fix that?

This is a question about what you did, how the theme is setup, and web development issues. So, asking outside the webmaster area would be suggested. I would contact the theme provider because they always know their products better than others and could give you a very fast answer.